# Determinant map is homomorphism and surjective.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I just came from a course of abstract algebra, and my teacher told us that the determinant map $\det : GL(n, \mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^\times$ is a surjective homomorphism.

Here, $GL(n, \mathbb{R}) = $ the set of $(n \times n)$ matrices $M$ such that $\det(M) \neq 0$

Why is $\det$ surjective?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that $$\det\begin{pmatrix}a&0&\cdots & 0\\
0&1&\cdots & 0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0 & 0 & \cdots &1\end{pmatrix} =a$$

Comment: Very elegant proof by construction.

Comment: That'll do :) nice (+1)

Comment: Why is this all that is needed?